# How to influence linebreak in Android Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-appwidget, line-breaks

I have an Appwidget displaying days until an event like:

> eventname (-231 days)

If possible I want to display this String in one line.
If the eventname is too long I want to display the full term in braces into a new line.
So that it is like:

> longeventname
>   (-231 days)

instead of:

> longeventname (-231
>   days)

(or anything similar)

Is there a way to archive this?
Can I make (-231 days) "atomic"?

string.getLength won't work since the size of the widget will vary by device.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between the number and "days".

That's `&#xA0;` for a string in XML, or `\u00A0` for a string in Java code.

Comment: Perfect! That ist exactly what I was looking for. "\u00A0" works perfect in Textview.

Comment: For people doing similar things here are two useful hints: First, there is also a non-breaking minus (\u2011) and second you can use a zero width space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space for a possible line break within a word.

Comment: Just a note: It seems that this is working in most cases. However even a non-breaking space will be kinda breaked if preceded by a period (there's no such thing as non-breaking period sadly). So this is not an option if you are working with abbrevations like "P. Howard"

Comment: For people that care about typography, maybe you'd like a [non-breaking hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) instead of a minus.